# ColdFusion If Statements Causing Spacing in <cfmail>

Tags: html, email, coldfusion

I'm sending an email out via the `<cfmail>` in ColdFusion, and I've encountered an issue where these line breaks appear in my email, despite my code not having that many line breaks to do that.

My co-worker told me that multi-line if statements can cause this, so I made them one-lined statements, but the line-breaking persists in my emails!

```
<cfmail ... >
    <strong><u>Event Details: </u></strong><br />
    <strong>What:</strong><cfif itemsforForm.normalTicket EQ true>Brunch</cfif><br />
    <strong>When:</strong> Sunday, August 17th, 2014<br />
    <cfif(itemsForForm.sponsor GT 0)>11:00am-2:00pm<br /></cfif> <!--- these cause the line breaks --->
    <cfif itemsforForm.normalTicket EQ true>11:30am-1:00pm<br /></cfif>
    <cfif itemsForForm.vipTicket EQ true>11:30am-2:00pm</cfif>
</cfmail>
```

For every `<cfif>` in my email, a linebreak appears in the output. Why is this happening?

Comment: nice name btw.  I assume you are talking about new lines OTHER than what your `<br />` tags are producing?  Just want to be absolutely clear...

Comment: Correct, MY `<br />` tags simply put text onto the immediate next line

Comment: It makes sense.  You're sending an email, and so (aside from the html) it treats the contents as literal text - **including the new lines**.  I'm guessing it's not your cfif causing problems; rather, I suspect that what you are telling it is "force a new line via this br tag, and oh by the way here's a carriage return, so put another new line in there as well".  What happens if you remove the <br /> tags right before the </cfif>?

Comment: then my text is simply smooshed together

Comment: I solved my problem btw, I'm writing an answer. It's really weird.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Look more closely at your code:

```
<cfmail ... >
    <strong><u>Event Details: </u></strong><br />
    <strong>What:</strong><cfif itemsforForm.normalTicket EQ true>Brunch</cfif><br />
    <strong>When:</strong> Sunday, August 17th, 2014<br />
    <cfif(itemsForForm.sponsor GT 0)>11:00am-2:00pm<br /></cfif> <!--- these cause the line breaks --->
    <cfif itemsforForm.normalTicket EQ true>11:30am-1:00pm<br /></cfif>
    <cfif itemsForForm.vipTicket EQ true>11:30am-2:00pm</cfif>
</cfmail>
```

At the end of each of those lines of code *is a line break*. That's why they're not one continuous line of code. And if your `if` conditions are false, you will not get the contents of the `<cfif>` block, but you'll *still* get the line break after the `</cfif>`

To work around this, enable cfoutput-only mode (with `<cfsettings>`), and then surround just the stuff you want in the mail message with `<cfoutput>` tags.

Or use CFScript rather than tags. It does not emit anything you don't tell it do.

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is that in the text editor, the code is indented. It seems that ColdFusion and `<cfmail>` take those indents into consideration when sending an email. So by un-indenting everything inside the cfmail tag, you get rid of any of those tabbed spaces making their way into your code and injecting linebreaks into seemingly nothing.

Comment: It's not weird. It's plain text. It is outputting exactly what you tell it to. If you tell it to output tabs it will do so. Tab is a legit character, the same as any other. No reason CF should remove them.

Comment: Look also at the type attribute.  You will get different results from text and html types.  You can also get different results in different email clients.

From the CF docs:
  text: specifies text/plain type.
  plain: specifies text/plain type.
  html: specifies text/html type.